# Filter log files based on date

Tags: linux, shell

I have a log file with every line that starts with the following date format.

```
2020-06-21 12:39:49 enginestart [INFO] total records found
```

I want to fetch logs dated from 2020-06-15 to 2020-06-21 and to display as output.

I have tried to grep, egrep, and sed and getting the expected result.

```
grep -E "2020-06-19|2020-06-20" logfile.* > file1
```

But the above-fetched log only from 20th

Thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser. I'm confused, what have you tried with `grep`? Somehow I don't see how something like `grep - P '^2020-06-(1[56789]|2[01])'` would _not_ work?! ... could you please edit your question and include _what_ you have tried? Then we can figure out exactly why it didn't work ...

Comment: Thanks @0xC0000022L for the update. I tried with sed as follows 

sudo sed -n '/^2020-06-21/p' logfile.* > file1 .  But not sure how to add multiple dates. Also I tried the command which you shared grep -P '^2020-06-(1[56789]|2[01])', the result is like  "logfile.1:2020-06-20 04:01:37 " only but not started from 15th and output contains logfile name

Comment: Well, you can get rid of the file name by passing `-h`. The `man grep` manual is your friend. The lines in your log file do _not_ start with 2020 then? Because my regex anchors it at the beginning of the line (the `^`).

Comment: the `grep -E` line you gave is lacking `()` to group the alternatives. I'm not sure it will work without. But the fact that _your_ `grep -E` invocation and my `grep -P` command both only show output from the 20th makes me think that you may want to look at the files. Also if some of the log files have been compressed (e.g. `.gz` suffix), grep will typically ignore them except when told otherwise.

Comment: Added -h argument and removed log file in the beginning but it is not fetching the log from 15th instead it collected from 20th only. Thanks for your help

Comment: _Again_ your command (covering 21st and 20th) shows only entries from 20th (which suggests that my comment about grouping _may_ be wrong). Mine covering 15th through 21st shows only entries from 20th. My conclusion from this is that you should look at your data and make sure that there are actually entries from those other days. For starters I'd look at what your glob expands to (`echo logfile.*`), make sure you don't have any compressed log files there (because then you'd need `zgrep` to treat those) and make sure that the log files even contain entries from those days and not just 20th ...

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` : `sed -n /From/,/To/p`.

```
sed -n /2020-06-19/,/2020-06-20/p logfile.* > file1
```